# Recharts range based bar charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I am using React Recharts and I want to build a date ranged bar chart similar to the example below (although data and look and feel will be different):

[Range based example chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKDH6.png)

The bars need to be stacked in the horizontal, and the Y Axis will be month-based.

Recharts doesn't have any example for this type of charts, and it has been quite difficult to find examples online.

Current code attempt: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-cookies-qt59r6

I think I almost got it working, except that the bars should be draw as a range and be in sync with the months from Y Axis.